# I can't prove (n - 0) = n with Idris

Tags: proof, idris

I am trying to prove, what to my mind is a reasonable theorem:

```
theorem1 : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> (n + (m - n)) = m
```

Proof by induction gets to the point where me need to prove this:

```
lemma1 : (n : Nat) -> (n - 0) = n
```

This is what happens when I try to prove it (the lemma, for simplicity sake) using the interactive prover:

```
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
{hole0} : (n : Nat) -> minus n 0 = n

> intros
----------              Other goals:              ----------
{hole0}
----------              Assumptions:              ----------
 n : Nat
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
{hole1} : minus n 0 = n

> trivial
Can't unify
        n = n
with
        minus n 0 = n

Specifically:
        Can't unify
                n
        with
                minus n 0
```

I felt like I must be missing something about the definition of minus, so I looked it up in the source:

```
||| Subtract natural numbers. If the second number is larger than the first, return 0.
total minus : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
minus Z        right     = Z
minus left     Z         = left
minus (S left) (S right) = minus left right
```

The definition I need is right there! `minus left Z = left`. My understanding was that Idris should just replace `minus m 0` with `m` here, and this is then reflexively true. What have I missed?

Comment: Idris is a dependently typed programming language, which makes proofs and programs synonymous due to the Curry-Howard isomorphism. I need to prove this theorem in code in order for my function to be well typed (I left the function out because explaining it would take up unnecessary space). Idris comes with an interactive prover for this reason. So the question is a question about how to use the programming language Idris, not about the maths itself.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, not being familiar with the language, but looking through some of the examples for this language - this is far from clear. Are `0` and `Z` always treated as synonymous or is there something required there to make it work?

Comment: Numeric literals are polymorphically overloaded like in Haskell. `Nat` is a member of the `Num` class, which one of the functions is `fromInteger`. And `fromInteger 0 = Z`. (There is also some special casing for Nat that goes on in the language itself and in the terminal I think.) In short I don't think that is the problem, although I am not certain enough to be entirely sure.

Comment: An aside: I don't think this is provable as stated.  Sure, it makes sense mathematically, but minus isn't really well-defined on Naturals in a total manner.
A failing case: if m is zero, and n is non-zero - zero minus anything is defined as zero.  So that then leaves you trying to prove (S k) + 0 = 0.
Maybe we need a better definition of a "minus" operation on Nats, else stop trying to use them for mathy proofs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately, the theorem that you want to prove here is not in fact true, because Idris naturals truncate subtraction at 0. A counterexample to your `theorem1` is `n=3, m=0`. Let's step through the evaluation:

First, we substitute:

```
3 + (0 - 3) = 0
```

Next, we desugar the syntax to the underlying Num instance, and put in the actual functions being called:

```
plus (S (S (S Z))) (minus Z (S (S (S Z))))) = Z
```

Idris is a strict, call-by-value language, so we evaluate the arguments to the functions first. Thus, we reduce the expression `minus Z (S (S (S Z))))`. Looking at [the definition of `minus`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/3820110510ad3968996a3a39ac52706ffb95aa45/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L69-L73), the first pattern applies, because the first argument is `Z`. So we have:

```
plus (S (S (S Z))) Z = Z
```

`plus` is recursive on its first argument, so the next step of evaluation yields:

```
S (plus (S (S Z)) Z) = Z
```

We continue this way until `plus` gets a `Z` as its first argument, at which point it returns its second argument `Z`, yielding the type:

```
S (S (S Z)) = Z
```

which we cannot construct an inhabitant for.

Sorry if the above seemed a bit pedantic and low-level, but its very important to take specific reduction steps into account when working with dependent types. That's the computation that you get "for free" inside of types, so it's good to arrange for it to produce convenient results.

pdxleif's solution above works well for your lemma, though. The case split on the first argument was necessary to get the pattern match in `minus` to work. Remember that it proceeds from top to bottom in the pattern matches, and the first pattern has a concrete constructor on the first argument, which means that reduction cannot proceed until it knows whether that constructor matched.

Answer (score 10):

Just playing around with the interactive editing, did a case split and proof search, yields:

```
lemma1 : (n : Nat) -> (n - 0) = n
lemma1 Z = refl
lemma1 (S k) = refl
```

This is obvious from the definition of minus, which is why it's simply refl.  Maybe it was balking when the input var was simply n, because it could have different behaviour if it was Z or something else?  Or the recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, a lot of arithmetic lemmas are already defined in the Idris Prelude, like yours:

```
total minusZeroRight : (left : Nat) -> left - 0 = left
minusZeroRight Z        = refl
minusZeroRight (S left) = refl
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake (the tactic language has been deprecated in favor of elaborator reflection), I will add that the way to prove your lemma in the tactic language is to invoke `induction n`.  You can then use `trivial` to show each case (after an `intros` in the inductive case).

```
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
{hole0} : (n : Nat) -> minus n 0 = n
-lemma1> intros
----------              Other goals:              ----------
{hole0}
----------              Assumptions:              ----------
 n : Nat
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
{hole1} : minus n 0 = n
-lemma1> induction n
----------              Other goals:              ----------
elim_S0,{hole1},{hole0}
----------              Assumptions:              ----------
 n : Nat
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
elim_Z0 : minus 0 0 = 0
-lemma1> trivial
----------              Other goals:              ----------
{hole1},{hole0}
----------              Assumptions:              ----------
 n : Nat
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
elim_S0 : (n__0 : Nat) ->
          (minus n__0 0 = n__0) -> minus (S n__0) 0 = S n__0
-lemma1> intros
----------              Other goals:              ----------
{hole8},elim_S0,{hole1},{hole0}
----------              Assumptions:              ----------
 n : Nat
 n__0 : Nat
 ihn__0 : minus n__0 0 = n__0
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
{hole9} : minus (S n__0) 0 = S n__0
-lemma1> trivial
lemma1: No more goals.
-lemma1> qed
Proof completed!
lemma1 = proof
  intros
  induction n
  trivial
  intros
  trivial
```