# Prove So (0 < m) -> (n ** m = S n)

Tags: proof, dependent-type, idris

I'm trying to make an Idris function of type `(j : Nat) -> {auto p : So (j < n)} -> Fin n` to convert a `Nat` into a `Fin n`. To get the `Z` case to work (and output `FZ`), I'm trying to prove that a proof of `0 < n` is sufficient to be able to make `FZ : Fin n`. But I can't work out how to do this.

I'm open to making a completely different function, as long as it can convert `Nat` values into `Fin n` values (where they exist). My goal is to have some other function that can convert any `Nat` into a `Mod n` value, so that, for example, `15 : Nat` is mapped to `3 : Mod 4`. My `Mod` type currently has a single constructor, `mkMod : Fin n -> Mod n`.

Comment: This will perhaps be better served at [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think it is still a programming problem as opposed to anything else. There are similar (answered) proof questions on SO (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519043/i-cant-prove-n-0-n-with-idris?rq=1)), and I seem more likely to get a response here.

Answer (score 1):

After learning about `LT : Nat -> Nat -> Type`, I took a different approach. I started with the declaration:

```
natToFin : (j : Nat) -> {auto p : j `LT` n} -> Fin n
natToFin {n} j {p} = ?natToFin_rhs_1
```

. Case-splitting on `n`, then on `p` in the `n = Z` case resulted in:

```
natToFin : (j : Nat) -> {auto p : j `LT` n} -> Fin n
natToFin {n = (S k)} j {p = p} = ?natToFin_rhs_2
```

, which is essentially the proof I was asking for. From there, I case-split on `j` and filled the zero case, leaving:

```
natToFin : (j : Nat) -> {auto p : j `LT` n} -> Fin n
natToFin {n = (S k)} Z = FZ
natToFin {n = (S k)} (S j) {p = p} = ?natToFin_rhs_3
```

. I wanted to fill `?natToFin_rhs_3` with `FS (natToFin j)`, but the type checker wasn't letting me. However, after a case split on `p`, it was fine:

```
natToFin : (j : Nat) -> {auto p : j `LT` n} -> Fin n
natToFin {n = (S k)} Z = FZ
natToFin {n = (S k)} (S j) {p = (LTESucc x)} = FS (natToFin j)
```

Finally, I added `total`, and it all checked out.

---

The only problem now is that Idris can't seem to find `LT` proofs automatically. This is what happens:

```
λΠ> the (Fin 6) (natToFin 2)
When elaborating argument p to function mod2.natToFin:
        Can't solve goal 
                LT (fromInteger 2) (fromInteger 6)
```

Is there any way to fix that?